# LatexDiff: Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: macros, urls, latexdiff

I have just created a diff file using `LatexDiff` but the newly created file seems to have issues with the `url` package, may be. I am getting following error.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.35 \expandafter\ifx\ifcsname \DIFadd{url}
                                           \endcsname\relax
```

The line 35 is

```
\expandafter\ifx\ifcsname \DIFadd{url}\endcsname\relax
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue? I have also pasted MWE below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}%
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithm,lipsum,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname%
      {\labelwidth 0.5em}{\labelwidth0pt\labelsep0pt}{}{}

\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color}\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}                      %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF SAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF FLOATSAFE PREAMBLE %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFaddtex{#1}}{#1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{\texorpdfstring{\DIFdeltex{#1}}{}} %DIF PREAMBLE
%DIF END PREAMBLE EXTENSION ADDED BY LATEXDIFF

\begin{document}

  \DIFdelbegin 
\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin \begin{thebibliography}{10}
\expandafter\ifx\ifcsname \DIFadd{url}\endcsname\relax
  \def\url\DIFadd{#1}{\texttt{\DIFadd{#1}}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname \DIFadd{urlprefix}\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname \DIFadd{href}\endcsname\relax
  \def\href\DIFadd{#1#2}{\DIFadd{#2}} \def\path\DIFadd{#1}{\DIFadd{#1}}\fi

\end{thebibliography}
\DIFaddend 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Something seems to have really thrown `latexdiff` in this case if it output this code directly. Did you edit it or is this what it gave you? If the former, I'd revert to what it gave you and make changes slowly. If the latter, what did this bit of your document look like before, and what does it look like now? Because `latexdiff` seems unable to cope with the changes.

Comment: My original diff document is 2000 lines of code..So I kept removing things slowly while getting the same error. I pasted the remaining diff document here.... I didn't edit any of the lines above..I just removed some stuff... I took a diff yesterday and it was working fine...I updated document at many places, added a footnote with url, and took diff again..but now its not working...

Comment: Should this be closed, do you think? Or...? I think we'd probably need to see the changes at this point in the file to be helpful. After all, 'fixing' the posted code isn't obviously useful at this point, is it?

Comment: I will try to update code incrementally now while diff is working fine.... But someone might have solution for it...I don't know... I am going to waste a couple of hours now... but if there is a solution, next person won't have to do it. So, once I identify the problem, find a solution, I will update this post again...

Comment: One of the TeX gurus might be able to diagnose it. What I meant was: that won't necessarily answer the question of why `latexdiff` generated the problem in the first place. I'm not sure, but for that you might need to know what was fed to it i.e. the relevant bit of the 2 files.

Comment: I had copies two tex file (old, new) and .bib and bbl for new tex file only... It was creating the above issue...I recopied new.tex, new.bib, new.bbl and old.tex, old.bib, old.bbl file in a new folder and ran diff... It worked all fine this time... How can we close this question? Sorry for asking this question in the first place...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been resolved to the asker's satisfaction by the asker and was caused by a failure to feed latexdiff sufficient things to satisfy its hunger. But the question doesn't reflect this as it wasn't known at the time and it is hard to see how to turn it into something which would be of wider use and findable and... er... The OP asked how to close it.

Comment: I wouldn't be sorry about asking it ;). Glad it got sorted.